# Bot for Comments on Instagram Giving Error

Tags: python, selenium, bots, instagram

the bot enters the profile, accesses the post but when pulling the comments from the txt file it closes, without making any comments.

````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
import instaloader
import random
import os.path

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\\Users\\Windows\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe")
    
    def sorteioInstagram():
    abrindo_instagram("inspiracaobiel", "biel123", "https://www.instagram.com/p/CoI52RJOqnT/")
    
        if os.path.isfile('seguidores.txt'):
            print("Arquivo de Seguidores já carregado...")
        else:
            pegar_seguidores('bielbibiel')
            
        comentandoPost()
    
    def abrindo_instagram(username,password, url):
    print("Abrindo Instagram...")
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
    sleep(2)
    print("Fazendo Login no Instagram...")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input\[@name="username"\]").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input\[@name="password"\]").send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button\[@type="submit"\]").click()
    
        sleep(10)
        print("Negando Solicitação de Segurança Instagram...")
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Agora não']").click()
        sleep(5)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Agora não']").click()
        sleep(4)
        print("Acessando o Post do sorteio...")
        driver.get(url)
    
    def pegar_seguidores(usuario):
    L = instaloader.Instaloader()
    L.login('inspiracaobiel', 'biel123')
    profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, usuario)
    
        print(f"Salvando Seguidores de {usuario}...")
        #Salvando Seguidores em Arquivo .TXT
        file = open("seguidores.txt", "a+")
        for followee in profile.get_followers():
            username = "@" + followee.username
            file.write(username + "\n")
        
        file.close()
    
    def comentandoPost():
    z = 0
    while 1 == 1:
    cmt = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*\[@id="react-root"\]/section/main/div/div\[1\]/article/div\[3\]/section\[3\]/div/form/textarea')
    cmt.click()
    comment = lendo_arquivo()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*\[@id="react-root"\]/section/main/div/div\[1\]/article/div\[3\]/section\[3\]/div/form/textarea').send_keys(comment)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*\[@id="react-root"\]/section/main/div/div\[1\]/article/div\[3\]/section\[3\]/div/form/textarea').send_keys(' ')
    sleep(10)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*\[@id="react-root"\]/section/main/div/div\[1\]/article/div\[3\]/section\[3\]/div/form/textarea').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    sleep(10)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//\*\[@id="react-root"\]/section/main/div/div\[1\]/article/div\[3\]/section\[3\]/div/form/textarea').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    z += 1
    print(f"{z}")
    sleep(60)
    
    def lendo_arquivo():
    with open("seguidores.txt", "r") as file:
    allText = file.read()
    words = list(map(str, allText.split()))
    return random.choice(words)
    
    sorteioInstagram()
    ```
    
    ERROR:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\\Users\\gabri\\Downloads\\Codigo Comentarios\\venv\\Scripts\\main.py", line 76, in \<module\>
    sorteioInstagram()
    File "c:\\Users\\gabri\\Downloads\\Codigo Comentarios\\venv\\Scripts\\main.py", line 17, in sorteioInstagram
    pegar_seguidores('bielbibiel')
    File "c:\\Users\\gabri\\Downloads\\Codigo Comentarios\\venv\\Scripts\\main.py", line 41, in pegar_seguidores
    L.login('inspiracaobiel', 'biel123')
    File "C:\\Users\\gabri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\instaloader\\instaloader.py", line 634, in login
    self.context.login(user, passwd)
    File "C:\\Users\\gabri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\instaloader\\instaloadercontext.py", line 239, in login
    raise ConnectionException("Login: Checkpoint required. Point your browser to "
    instaloader.exceptions.ConnectionException: Login: Checkpoint required. Point your browser to https://www.instagram.com/challenge/action/AXG6u8rHRprRccgzcgLKpQNJzv0wH2s1vajDDBvJi2xj-ypRREOtDgZK3e5Ee8HekhTocA0/AfxgQISXQXjHI8kasJEBP020fZ1GKKqFXXJGeaFzdDei1KKj2Pc3OVuZl5K_J3Og2Mxa0Yx64gubOg/ffc_XxXKP7ukaNEpowIhzsecXIF8lbX5oShdPs03HikkaCikTbJ50ZWn38x98bzTC5ZI/ - follow the instructions, then retry.

I tried to fix the comment part but I couldn't, but I couldn't resolve the error, it keeps closing and not making any comment.
````